# Nested level logic

Tags: logic, pseudocode

I have to write a logic for a problem and use it on a landing page. I am unable to write it.

1 - IT 1

2 - IT 1

3 - IT 1

4 - IT 2

5 - IT 2

6 - IT 2

7 - IT 2

8 - IT 3

9 - IT 4

Problem Statement:
-Till someone is selecting 1 or 2 or 3, only IT 1 is suggested
-When someone chooses 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 and anything with value 3 or below , IT 2 is suggested
-When someone chooses 8 or or 8 + anything below 8 then IT 3 is suggested
-When someone chooses 9 and anything with a value below 9 then IT 4 is suggested.

I was using if condition but it seems that whenever IT2 is satisfied IT3 is also satisfied. How to write the logic?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/bhanusingh/7fxet35h/9/

Don't nest your ifs. Just write four ifs like in your problem description and make a helper function to make it easier to read.

Below is a pseudo code where numbers represent references to checkboxes. isAnySelected is a helper function that takes a list of checkbox references and returns true if any of those checkboxes are checked.

```
if (isAnySelected([1,2,3]) )
   return IT1
if (isAnySelected([4,5,6,7]) AND isAnySelected([1,2,3]) )
  return IT2
if (isAnySelected([8]) AND NOT isAnySelected([9])) 
   return IT3
if (isAnySelected([9]) AND isAnySelected([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
  return IT4
```

Note that I added "not 9" rule to #3 so that 8 and 9 selected produces IT4

Solved on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/bpukvf/i_got_a_very_complex_problem_for_me_i_can_only/enxst62?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x